# In SQL (PSQL), how to group by partitions of rows (how to do nested group by)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics, psql

Wording of the question needs improvement, I'm not sure how to accurately describe it.

Given a table `foo`, count how many languages each person can speak, grouped by format. Example:

```
 name |  format  |  language
------+----------+------------
 abe  | compiled | golang
 abe  | compiled | c
 abe  | scripted | javascript
 jon  | scripted | ruby
 jon  | scripted | javascript
 wut  | spoken   | english
(6 rows)
```

Result:

```
 name |  format  |  count
------+----------+------------
 abe  | compiled | 2
 abe  | scripted | 1
 jon  | scripted | 2
 wut  | spoken   | 1
```

Example data can be created using:

```
create table foo
(
  name varchar(40) not null,
  format varchar(40) not null,
  language varchar(40) not null
);
insert into foo
values
  ( 'abe', 'compiled', 'golang' ),
  ( 'abe', 'compiled', 'c' ),
  ( 'abe', 'scripted', 'javascript' ),
  ( 'jon', 'scripted', 'ruby' ),
  ( 'jon', 'scripted', 'javascript' ),
  ( 'wut', 'spoken', 'english' )
;
```

I've tried using windowing functions `count(*) over (partition by format)` but it doesn't squash rows, and it would require a nested window by name, and then by format, whereas `count(*) ... group by name` used on its own would squash the result into one row per name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` clause :

```
select name, format, count(*)
from foo
group by name, format;
```

However, if you want to go with *window* function then you can also do that :

```
select distinct name, format, 
       count(*) over (partition by name, format)
from foo f;
```

Comment: wow that's quite simple, did not know the clauses themselves can be nested like that, thanks!!